# jQuery popeye don't want to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I can't provide the code but you can see it on the web.
[Here is the Link](http://bestinvest.ge/en/?transaction=3&minrooms=1&maxrooms=100&minprice=&maxprice=)

All scripts work correctly on the web but I can't configure the popeye and find the problem... Can anyone check it out?

When I check with google errors it marks the following code in jquery 1.7.2.

```
return makeArray( context.querySelectorAll( "[id='" + nid + "'] " + query ), extra )
```

Popeye's website [is here](http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/jquery/popeye/demo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but this is what i got as errors using chrome console, some resources are not loaded and there is undefined object passed to the popeye i believe

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://bestinvest.ge/js/script.js". header.js:2

(anonymous function) header.js:2

GET http://bestinvest.ge/en/upload/sresize.php?src=building/uploads/41/&w=160&h=110 400 (Bad Request) /en/?transaction=3&minrooms=1&maxrooms=100&minprice=&maxprice=:739

GET http://bestinvest.ge/en/upload/sresize.php?src=building/uploads/41/&w=280&h=180 400 (Bad Request) /en/?transaction=3&minrooms=1&maxrooms=100&minprice=&maxprice=:746
3



Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined jquery.js:8480
jQuery.fn.extend.fadeTo jquery.js:8480
showImage jquery.popeye-2.1.js:288
$.fn.popeye.each.$self.mouseenter.ismouseover jquery.popeye-2.1.js:642
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3332
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2941
```

Hope this help, good luck

Comment: After looking through the source, I couldn't find jQuery anywhere, so your find of `call method 'show' of undefined jquery.js` may be spot on.

Comment: Thanks you all for give me your free time. i found error and fix it.